# Écriture inclusive : question à propos d'un suffixe de formation du féminin

Tags: suffixes, écriture-inclusive

Dans plusieurs textes on trouve le nouveau mot « professeure » ; il est issu des cogitations de certains féministes et l'Académie française rejette ce mot ainsi que d'autres tels que « auteure » et « docteure ». On trouve cependant la prise de position suivante dans une [déclaration de l'Académie](https://forum.lefigaro.fr/forum/affich-340-professeure-ou-professeur)

> *"Cependant, la Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie considère – et l’Académie française a fait siennes ces conclusions – que cette indifférence juridique et politique au sexe des individus « peut s’incliner, toutefois, devant le désir légitime des individus de mettre en accord, pour les communications qui leur sont personnellement destinées, leur appellation avec leur identité propre. » Elle estime que, « s’agissant des **appellations utilisées dans la vie courante** (entretiens, correspondances, relations personnelles) concernant les fonctions et les grades, rien ne s’oppose, **à la demande expresse des individus**, à ce qu’elles soient mises en accord avec le sexe de ceux qui les portent et soient féminisées **ou** maintenues au masculin générique selon le cas »."*

Force est de conclure que l'écriture inclusive a déjà fait une petite percée dans le langage  et une question comme la suivante se trouve assez justifiée.

Pourquoi la féminisation du mot « professeur » doit elle être « professeure », qui ne se distingue pas phonétiquement du  « nom pour les hommes » de toute façon, et non « professeuse » alors que pour nombre d'autres mots la formation est sur le modèle « eur/euse » : chanteur/chanteuse, vendeur/vendeuse, ouvreur/ouvreuse, accoucheur/accoucheuse, annonceur/annonceuse… 
Pourquoi doit-on dire « docteure » alors qu'il existe déjà « doctoresse », lequel mot marque bien une « fonction féminine », si parler d'une telle fonction a un sens quelconque?

Comment doit-on comprendre cet empilement sur le mot pour la « fonction dans le cas des hommes »? Doit-on prononcer le e?

Comment: Ce qu'en dit l'Office québécois de la langue française: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4015. On peut désapprouver, mais pas faire comme si ça n'existait pas, tout au moins de ce côté-ci de la mare aux sardines.

Comment: Un personnage public connu, Lionel Jospin, signe la préface de *Femme j'écris ton nom*, y affirmant que *«D’ores et déjà, avec l’aide des
médias, qui ont assimilé son sens, cette démarche progresse et
les querelles sur « le » ou « la » ministre, lorsqu’une femme
occupe ces fonctions, appartiendront bientôt au passé.»* Affirmer que l'écriture inclusive a un pied dans la porte, c'est un peu refuser de regarder de l'autre côté de la clôture (on pourrait sans doute aussi affirmer la même chose de M. Jospin, je le concède).

Comment: Par ailleurs, un lien plus directe à la citation de la question, si elle intéresse l'OP: [sur le site même de l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/la-feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-fonctions-grades-ou-titres-mise-au-point-de-lacademie).

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Je n'avais pas du tout en tête l'état du Québec; je puise mes sources dans des articles  écrits par des français, tout à fait ignorant que  ce phénomène  soit essentiellement propre au Québec (Est-ce le cas?). Il me semble que la caratérisation « pied dans la porte » soit justifiée au vu de la concession faite par l'Académie : il est clairement stipulé que le choix est toléré dans le domaine des «  entretiens, correspondances, relations personnelles » ; il me semble aussi qu'il y ait en cela une concession très importante au vu qu'une pratique solide pourrait en découler.

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Il y avait une erreur de ma part : traduction inconsciente de l'anglais « foot in the door », qui était de plus mal assimilé. Désolé d'avoir créé un problème et merci de le signaler.

Comment: Probablement plus typique au Québec qu'ailleurs, oui. Mais juste comme je répondais à une autre question, je suis arrivé sur la présentation de la [professeure Mireille Huchon](http://lettres.sorbonne-universite.fr/HUCHON-Mireille?lettre=h), de la Sorbonne. Ça survenait bien à propos.

Comment: @Montéedelait : +1 pour votre comm... et ça tombe bien... la plus grande qualité que je trouve à cet homme étant... sa femme! (Cela reconnaissant de même que sa mère était quelqu'**un** de **très bien** surtout) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Des explications sont proposées par [Éliane Viennot](http://www.elianeviennot.fr/publications1.html) dans certains de ses ouvrages (que je conseille très vivement au sujet des évolutions de la langue française concernant le genre).

Si `professeure` est utilisé au lieu de `professeuse` ou `auteure` au lieu d'`autrice`, c'est pour deux principales raisons:

- Les terminaisons en `-eure` ne sont pas audibles à l'oral permettant, notamment pour ce que l'Académie appelle les fonctions, de "camoufler" le féminin. Ce compromis permet de rendre la terminaison plus acceptable pour les opposants aux formes féminines.
- Lors des débuts de l'écriture inclusive, tout un ensemble de féminins ont du être créés. Les anciennes terminaisons féminines ayant été oubliées depuis quelques siècles, le choix a été celui de la rapidité et de la facilité au détriment d'une recherche plus poussée.

La féminisation de `docteur` n'est donc pas obligatoirement `docteure`, on peut aussi utiliser `doctoresse`, `doctrice` ou `docteuse` qui [existaient il y a un certain temps](http://siefar.org/la-guerre-des-mots-dictionnaire/les-mots-de-a-a-z-lettre-d/#Docteuse). Comme pour l'usage des parenthèses, qui est maintenant déconseillé au profit des points ou points médians, l'écriture dite inclusive est en pleine construction et les règles varient au fur et à mesure des trouvailles et réflexions sur le sujet.

Enfin comme le dit l'Académie, seul l'usage tranchera sur le long terme, en attendant mon avis personnel est de privilégier les formes qui font ressortir la logique interne du français, par exemple `autrice` car construit sur `auctor` tout comme `spectatrice` se construit autour de `spectator`.