# Quels sont les mots finissant en -eur qui n'ont pas de féminin?

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour! je prépare un projet de Français et je vous demande bien, quels sont les mots en -eur n'ayant pas de forme féminine?
Merci bcp!

Answer (score 3):

La plupart des noms communs français ont un seul genre, masculin ou féminin, indépendamment de leur terminaison.

Le fait qu'*ascenseur* soit masculin et qu'il n'existe pas de forme *ascenseuse* n'est probablement pas très pertinent pour un projet de français.

J'imagine donc que la question porte plutôt sur des noms de métiers ou d'occupation, fréquemment en -eur, pour lesquels la question de l'absence ou du traitement particulier du féminin a pu faire polémique.

La tendance est simplement d'ajouter un *-e* final pour le féminin, ce qui va à l'encontre des féminins traditionnels en -euse (danseur/danseuse, vendeur/vendeuse) ou en *-trice* pour les masculins en *-teur* (navigateur/navigatrice).

Difficile de donner une liste de mots n'ayant pas de forme féminine puisqu'il est très simple d'en créer une en ajoutant un -e, et que petit à petit l'usage de ces formes nouvelles se répand.

Ce point a déjà été abordé dans cette question: [Écriture inclusive : question à propos d'un suffixe de formation du féminin](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32745/)

Answer (score 2):

Selon *Le Petit Robert de la langue française 2012*, il y a 614 noms qui se terminent en -*eur* et n'ont pas de forme féminine.

[image: Capture d'écran]

Comment: L'accès du dico est payant ou pas?

Comment: Oui, il faut soit acheter le logiciel, soit s'y abonner sur le site de Robert.

Comment: Alors, peut-être faut-il le dire à Adem.